# Get the title child of bs4 element python using findall?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using the find_all method to get some elements like so:

```
elements = soup.find_all('a', {'class': "watchlink"})
```

to get elements like following:

```
<a class="watchlink" href="https://www1.swatchseries.to/freecale.html?r=iexyJrjdCI6InRuT0tnVpFR1VjBVZUmNFZHJiN09tLWENDT25oOGNrS3c0SkkzTDRLSXBUK1VCUXlOd0NJNW1uWWJkWVUrRkluejciLCJpdiI6IjEyNjViZTg2NTU3NWVkN2ZlNDZiNWVjZTA5NjkxNDE2IiwicyI6IjBhZGYxOGNmY2ExMzA5YjEifQ==" onclick="$(this).css('color','#AE3939'); $(this).css('text-decoration','line-through');" rel="nofollow" style="cursor:pointer;" target="_blank" title="mixdrop.co">Watch<span> This</span> Link!</a>
```

I am not able to get the tile only like so:

```
    for x in elements:
        print(x['title'])
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/CobraCommander/PycharmProjects/999/get_vidtodo_links.py", line 25, in <module>
  print(x['title'])
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1016, in __getitem__
  return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'title'
```

It does work however for the other attributes, like "href" for example.

How do I get the title: "mixdrop.co" from my element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that you access the right `anchor` tags with `title` as i believe there's tags with same class name but without `title`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a class="watchlink" href="https://www1.swatchseries.to/freecale.html?r=iexyJrjdCI6InRuT0tnVpFR1VjBVZUmNFZHJiN09tLWENDT25oOGNrS3c0SkkzTDRLSXBUK1VCUXlOd0NJNW1uWWJkWVUrRkluejciLCJpdiI6IjEyNjViZTg2NTU3NWVkN2ZlNDZiNWVjZTA5NjkxNDE2IiwicyI6IjBhZGYxOGNmY2ExMzA5YjEifQ==" onclick="$(this).css('color','#AE3939'); $(this).css('text-decoration','line-through');" rel="nofollow" style="cursor:pointer;" target="_blank" title="mixdrop.co">Watch<span> This</span> Link!</a>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

goal = [item['title'] for item in soup.findAll(
    "a", {'class': 'watchlink', 'title': True})]

print(goal)
```

Output:

```
['mixdrop.co']
```